# Attaching attachments in Allure reports using cucumber jvm after hooks

Tags: cucumber-jvm, allure

With Allure report framework when a step fails we can attach a screenshot or logs by calling a method with @Attachment annotation.

```
@Attachment(value = "Message", type = "text/plain")
public String attachLog(){
    return "Hello, Test failed!";
}
```

But this means I have to explicitly call this method ( attachLog() ) in every step before assertions. Which seems unreasonable.

In CucumberJvm the "after" hooks are a great way to attach  screenshots or logs. we do this by checking the scenario status and attach screenshots/logs based on the outcome.

I tried invoking the above method ( attachLog() ) in the cucumberJvm "after" hook. But unfortunately did not work.

Is there a solution to make this work?

Cheers
Vinod

Answer (score 1):

You can override test failure method from `ru.yandex.qatools.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureRunListener`

```
public class CustomAllureListener extends AllureRunListener {


    @Override
    public void testFailure(Failure failure) {
        super.testFailure(failure);
        if (!failure.getDescription().isSuite()) { // check is needed to avoid double attaching
             attachFailed();
        }
    }

    @Attachment(value = "Message", type = "text/plain")
    public String attachFailed(){
        return "Test failed!";
    }
}
```

And don't forget to change listener in `pom.xml` file

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                </argLine>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>com.mycompany.testing.CustomAllureListener</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```